# Same Tweepy script works just with some hashtags and not with others

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets

I made this script to get 3200 Tweets with some hashtag,
it works for some hastags, and then for others it gets me just 200 or less tweets... **WHY????:**

```
def getHashtag(hashtag):
    data={'created_at':[],'full_text':[],'favorite_count':[],'retweet_count':[],'place':[],'coordinates':[]}
    query = hashtag
    max_tweets = 3200
    n=0
    for stat in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets):
        try:
            n+=1
            data['created_at'].append(stat.created_at)
            data['full_text'].append([stat.text])
            data['favorite_count'].append(stat.favorite_count)
            data['retweet_count'].append(stat.retweet_count)
            data['place'].append(stat.place)
            data['coordinates'].append(stat.coordinates)
            if n==800:
                for i in range(1,300):
                    time.sleep(1)

                n=0

            print(n)
        except:
            break

    _=pd.DataFrame(data)
    save=open('%stuitsPd.pickle' % hashtag,'wb')
    pickle.dump(_,save)
    save.close()
```

Comment: What are examples of the hashtags that return many, and fewer, results? Perhaps the ones with < 200 hits have not been used much in the past week.

Comment: Well... no, the hashtags i'm searching are from mexican politics like #amlo or #anaya. So I know they are pretty common. Also, sometimes they are <200 and maybe half hour later they are thousands. So I do not known if it is my code, or my rate of calls to Twitter.